# Method call throws an "undefined method" error

Tags: ruby

I created a method with the code

```
def delayTime(time, intervalString)
  if time > 0  
    sleep(time / time)  
    puts intervalString  
    time -=1  
    delayTime(time, intervalString)  
  end  
end
```

but when I call it with

```
delayTime(1, ".")
```

it throws the error

```
`<class:Main>': undefined method 'delayTime' for Main:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: A full context is missing. That code should work, so my hypothesis is that the invocation context is different than the definition context.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why is throws this error. There is almost nothing else in the program, just a few `puts` and if statements. I don't see why it's not working. The full code, notably not mine, I am simply to make it more efficient or something like that, is here: http://pastebin.com/JehGB7fK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call like below :

```
Main.new.delayTime(1, ".")
```

`delayTime` is an instance method of your class `Main`. So the receiver should be an instance of the class `Main`. Looking at your error,I am sure you called it as `Main.delayTime`. But you can't call it this way. If you want to call it as `Main.delayTime`,then you need to define your method as below :

```
def self.delayTime(time, intervalString)
  if time > 0  
    sleep(time / time)  
    puts intervalString  
    time -=1  
    delayTime(time, intervalString)  
  end  
end
```

**Corrected**

```
class Main
  #Variables
  name = ""
  answer_wonder = ""
  answer_math = ""
  result_math = 0
  #End of Variables
def self.delayTime(time, intervalString)
    if time > 0
      sleep(time / time)
      puts intervalString
      time -=1
      delayTime(time, intervalString)
    end
end
end #Class end

Main.delayTime(1, ".")
```

Comment: That simply thew `<class:Main>': undefined method 'delayTime' for #<Main:0x27aa178> (NoMethodError)` at me. Is that the only line I must change, or...?

Comment: New code - http://pastebin.com/tuF1LTL9 I've put everything else as a comment, and done what you said. Still the error. Sorry, I only started Ruby yesterday.

Comment: @IHazABone Try now..:) You doing a mess with basic things :)

Comment: I created an entirely new class in a new project and used just that code and it STILL threw the same error...

Comment: I restarted my computer and it decided to work. What. Hm. That's extremely strange, as the error seemed to have nothing to do with the computer itself, or the software for that matter. Oh well, sorry for your troubles.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is a result of how Ruby interprets the code. Your code consists of a class definition with an included class body (between `class` and the final `end`).

The class body is executed once, when the Ruby interpreter loads the file. As the interpreter processes the body the various statements are executed. When the wanted call to `delayTime` is encountered, that method has not been defined yet.

You have a couple of ways to deal with this. First off you might not want the code in the class body to be executed at load time, but instead when you call a method on the class (instance or class itself).

This can be achieved by wrapping your logic inside a method, e.g.

```
class Main
  def execute
    ... 
    delayTime
    ...
  end

  def delayTime
    ...
  end
end

Main.new.execute # Instantiate the class and execute the wanted method
```

However if you really want to execute the code at load time, and still call the defined method, you need to make a few changes. First off you need to define the method before the calling code is executed (at load time, remember). As well as defining it before the calling code, you need to make sure you define it as a class method (either by prefixing the method with `self.` or by opening up the class definition with the `class << self ... end` syntax and defining the method there). This is needed since the instance of the class is not known as the class body is executed. Chicken and egg situation.

The modified version would look something like this:

```
class Main
  def self.delayTime
    ...
  end

  ... 
  self.delayTime # Could also be called as Main.delayTime
  ....
end
```

And finally an example by opening up the class definition:

```
class Main
  class << self
    def delayTime
      ...
    end
  end

  ... 
  self.delayTime # Could also be called as Main.delayTime
  ....
end
```

Note however that by placing logic in the class body itself, you might encounter some unwanted issues as your program grows beyond a single file and you start to include (`require`/`load`) multiple files. But, thats a story for another day.

Comment: So, between `class Main` and the `end` for that, I should only declare variables and/or methods? Everything else goes outside that?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve. Judging by the code you pasted (pastebin) I would recommend that you encapsulate all your logic (including variables) inside a method that you call on an instance of the class (by calling for instance `Main.new.execute`, if `execute` is the name of the defined method). Another option is to make both methods (`execute` and `delayTime`) class methods, that way to don't have to instantiate the class before calling it. E.g. `Main.execute`.